# Multiple adverts on the same page with google-swiffy

Tags: google-swiffy

I have a page that is to display multiple ads.  So far and for the current swiffy runtime (7.2.0) even if I setup two stages, only the last one defined starts.

```
var stage1 = new swiffy.Stage(document.getElementById('container1'),
      swiffyobject1, {  });
stage1.start();
var stage2 = new swiffy.Stage(document.getElementById('container2'),
      swiffyobject2, {  });
stage2.start();
```

if I do that, only stage2 will start.  Is there any solution so I can have more than one such stages on one page?  Only working way was to iframe each add as a page, which I don't really like.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe it is a issue on swiffy v.7.2.0

I just pointed to version 5.2 and get it back working again.

Just change your script reference to:
https://www.gstatic.com/swiffy/v5.2/runtime.js

Answer (score 1):

All the swiffy json objects should be configured to use the same Action Script.
Turn ON the Action Script 3 for all with:

**{"as3":true,...}**

or turn OFF the Action Script 3 for all with:

**{"as3":false,...}**

I hope it will works.